# "Build now" in jenkins not getting fired immediately after any code changes in gitlab repo?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, jenkins-workflow

"Build now" in jenkins not getting fired immediately after any code changes in gitlab repo . And its taking more than a day to build .But if I am manually doing "Build now" immediately changes are reflecting .

Comment: have you set the webhooks from gitlab? [try](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gitlab+Hook+Plugin)

Comment: @Amityo yes i have tried webhooks .only when i am clicking on "test settings" its fired up . In "Execute shell" of jenkins i have "source /xchanging_env/bin/activate   # Activate the virtualenv
cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/xchanging
#pip install -r requirements.txt   # Install or upgrade dependencies
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate                  # Apply South's database migrations
sudo service nginx restart
gunicorn xchanging.wsgi:application  --bind=mydomainip:portno" .But the build is takeing more than 1day to build .All the are executing within a second .

Comment: I guess that the one day build is because of configuration specifing to build each day. Try to look at Jenkins logs to check if you receice the hooks. And in gitlab search for the status of the hooks